# PlayFramework Scala Test - Get instance of a class via dependency injector

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, playframework-2.4

I am using Scala Test for testing my service layer. I am struggling to getinstance of service class in my test. My test class is as below

```
class SmsServiceSpec extends BaseSpec with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures {

implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication()

"SMS Service" must {
   "able to send SMS" in {

    val smsService =  //not sure how to get instance of class here => app.injector.getInstance[SmsService]

    whenReady(smsService.sendSms("9XXXXXXX", "This is test message")) { res =>
      res mustBe true
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Edited Code, as per @easel

```
class SmsServiceSpec extends BaseSpec with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures {

 "SMS Service" must {
"able to send SMS" in {

  @Inject val smsService: SmsService = null //not sure how to get instance of class here => app.injector.getInstance[SmsService]

  whenReady(smsService.sendSms("98XXXXXX", "This is test message")) { res =>
    res mustBe true
  }
}
}

}
```

I am not sure how to get instance of SMS service in the above code.

Thanks,

Comment: So I am not as familiar with 2.4 and I know things changed with DI but in my app I use 2.3 w/Guice and for Unit tests in my setup I instantiate the class myself and pass in the dependencies or mocks etc. Can you do something similar?

Comment: What's wrong with the line you have commented out. In play 2.4 it should "just work" as long as SmsService is annotated with @Inject or has a 0-argument constructor.

Comment: @barry - This particular test cannot work with mocks. I want to test if I am actually receiving SMS on my phone :(

Comment: @easel - I updated my code above, but I still get my property as null.

Comment: Did you try just using app.injector.getInstance[SmsService]?

Comment: @easel - Tried doing that, sbt complains that getInstance is not a function of injector. Not sure if I am missing any import

Comment: I think you have something else going on then. Perhaps missing libraries or config or an overridden global module. I have a trait like the following that I mix in to my tests for ease of reference to services, etc, and it "just works". trait Injections {
  def app: Application

  implicit lazy val injector = app.injector

  def actorSystem: ActorSystem = injector.instanceOf[ActorSystem]

Comment: @easel - Thanks for this, it could be really helpful. I atleast know where to start with :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guice for dependency injection. It is a good practice to abstract services at compilation time and specify a binding between services abstractions and their implementations at run time.

For example,

> class SmsServiceImpl extends SmsService
>
> bind(classOf[SmsService]).to(classOf[SmsServiceImpl])

This, https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo, is a simple but standard application using Play 2.4.2, ReactiveMongo, and Guice (for dependency injection).